# DateTime problem in asp.net

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm using v.s 2008 with c#. 
I have a .rdlc file and it using a objectdatasource. ods has two datetime parameters. 
That datetime parameter's format must be dd-MM-yyy. but that time threw an exception. 
Exception is : An error has occurred during report processing.
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

My code is :

```
        int iBaslangicYil = txtIlkTarih.Text.Substring(6, 4).To<int>();
        int iBaslangicGun = txtIlkTarih.Text.Substring(0, 2).To<int>();
        int iBAslangicAy = txtIlkTarih.Text.Substring(3, 2).To<int>();
        DateTime dtBaslangic = new DateTime(iBaslangicYil, iBAslangicAy, iBaslangicGun);

        int iBitisYil = txtIkinciTarih.Text.Substring(6, 4).To<int>();
        int iBitisGun = txtIkinciTarih.Text.Substring(0, 2).To<int>();
        int iBitisAy = txtIkinciTarih.Text.Substring(3, 2).To<int>();
        DateTime dtBitis = new DateTime(iBitisYil, iBitisAy, iBitisGun);

        rvTarihAraliginaGoreSeansSayilari.Visible = true;
        odsTarihAraliginaGoreSeansSayisi.SelectParameters.Add("refTarih1",DbType.DateTime,dtBaslangic.ToString());
        odsTarihAraliginaGoreSeansSayisi.SelectParameters.Add("refTarih2", System.Data.DbType.DateTime, dtBitis.ToString());
        odsTarihAraliginaGoreSeansSayisi.DataBind();
        rvTarihAraliginaGoreSeansSayilari.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument for adding `SelectParameters` to an `ObjectDataSource` should be a `TypeCode` enum

```
odsTarihAraliginaGoreSeansSayisi.SelectParameters.Add("refTarih1",TypeCode.DateTime ,dtBaslangic.ToString());
```

Comment: There are overloads that take `TypeCode` or `DbType`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parametercollection.add.aspx

Comment: @Luke - thanks. I'm using .NET 2.0 at the moment and that overload doesn't exist in it (.NET 3.5) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the format of the string explicitly when you call `ToString`:

```
odsTarihAraliginaGoreSeansSayisi.SelectParameters
    .Add("refTarih1", DbType.DateTime, dtBaslangic.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd");
odsTarihAraliginaGoreSeansSayisi.SelectParameters
    .Add("refTarih2", DbType.DateTime, dtBitis.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `SelectParameters.Add` issue has been addressed by other answers; but to make your code easier, you might also want to look at `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
string s = "01-02-2003";
DateTime when = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // sine no locale issues in the above
```

Answer (score 0):

In the objectdatasource, under `selectparameters`, try changing the parameter type from datetime to string. Then format your input values as `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`. The DateTime type gives a lot of problems + sql automatically converts string of that format to DateTime.